# Efficient way to loop through data to return Object in Web api c#

Tags: c#, linq, api, rest

I have data that I need to to loop through and convert it JSOn format with nested array.
Below is my data
Now I see two option to do this process

```
ClientName      Dno     DnoId     Dfull        DfullId
ClientA        AB342A   16711   AB342A-J2015    1
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J20131   2
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J20151   3
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J2015T   4
ClientB        BD944A   6679    BD944A-D20131   5
ClientC        CA778A   12073   CA778A-J20151   6
```

And Output I want is like below

```
[{  
    "ClientName":"ClientA",
    "DnoList":[  
      {  
        "DnoId":"16711",
        "Dno":"AB342A",
        "DfullList":[  
          {  
            "DfullId":"1",
            "Dfull":"AB342A-J2015"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "ClientName":"ClientB"
    "DnoList":[  
      {  
        "DnoId":"6648",
        "Dno":"AB544A",
        "DfullList":[  
          {  
            "DfullId":"2",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J20131"
          },{  
            "DfullId":"3",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J20151"
          },{  
            "DfullId":"4",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J2015T"
          }
        ]
      },
      {  
        "DnoId":"6679",
        "Dno":"BD944A",
        "DfullList":[ {  
            "DfullId":"5",
            "Dfull":"BD944A-D20131"
          } ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Now I find two approach to get this type of output
1. Create three different class with nested array then loop through that
2. loop through datatable/list ??

But I am not getting close to it.

Can anyone help with with better approach.

EDIT : Linq query I am using is as below

```
var objlist = from tblA in context.TableA
                    join tblB in context.TableB on tblA.lng_clientid equals tblB.lng_id
                    where tblA.int_deleted.Equals(0)                              
                    select new Client()
                    {
                        ClientName = tblA.str_client,,
                        DnoId = tblA.lng_dnoid,
                        Dno = tblA.str_dno,
                        Dfull = tblA.str_dfull,
                        DfullId = tblA.lng_id
                    };
```

and class as below

```
public class Client
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public int DnoId { get; set; }
        public string Dno { get; set; }
        public string Dfull { get; set; }
        public int DfullId { get; set; }
    }
```

Other Approach I have is different class as below

```
public class MyData
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<DnoList> DnoLists { get; set; }
}

public class DnoList
{
    public int DnoId { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; }
    public List<DfullList> DfullLists { get; set; }
}

public class DfullList
{
    public int DfullId { get; set; }
    public string Dfull { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you could loop through the table to form a similar data structure and serialize it.

Comment: @Mahajan344  What you want? To define best class structure for the above scenario ... or how to go with one class scenario??

Comment: Please update your LINQ query to include `DnoId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking for is a classical nested grouping.

Let start with a flat query presenting your data (you can get the desired output by embedding it into the grouping query, but let keep it separately for better readability - it will not be executed separately):

```
var clients = 
    from tblA in context.TableA
    join tblB in context.TableB on tblA.lng_clientid equals tblB.lng_id
    where tblA.int_deleted.Equals(0)                              
    select new Client()
    {
        ClientName = tblA.str_client,,
        DnoId = tblA.lng_dnoid,
        Dno = tblA.str_dno,
        Dfull = tblA.str_dfull,
        DfullId = tblA.lng_id
    };
```

To transform it to the desired output format, you need to perform nested grouping,  first by `ClientName`, then by `DnoId, Dno`, and project the results into a custom classes you've created:

```
var output =
    (from c in clients
     group c by c.ClientName into clientNameGroup
     select new MyData
     {
         ClientName = clientNameGroup.Key,
         DnoLists = (
             from c in clientNameGroup
             group c by new { c.DnoId, c.Dno } into dnoGroup
             select new DnoList
             {
                 Dno = dnoGroup.Key.Dno,
                 DnoId = dnoGroup.Key.DnoId,
                 DfullLists = (
                     from c in dnoGroup
                     select new DfullList
                     {
                         Dfull = c.Dfull,
                         DfullId = c.DfullId
                     }
                 ).ToList()
             }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have one question that what if I have one more column say ClientId along with Clientname in Mydata class.. then how do i select clientid in your later query ?? I tried with clientNameGroup.Key.Clientid but its giving error

Comment: Is there any other way to select that column

Comment: You need to include it in the first grouping, i.e. instead of `by c.ClientName` you'll use `by new { c.ClientId, c.ClientName }` and then `select new MyData { ClientId = clientNameGroup.Key.ClientId, ClientName = clientNameGroup.Key.ClientName, ... (the rest)`. If you update your question with including that column in the base query, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I got it .. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that you have your list of Clients as:

```
public class Client {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; }
    public string DnoId { get; set; }
    public string Dfull { get; set; }
    public string DfullId { get; set; }
}
```

you could extract your result as this (not efficient, nor clean):

```
            List<Client> clients = ... //your list here;

            clients.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(
                    x =>
                        new
                        {
                            ClientName = x.Key,
                            DnoList =
                                x.ToList()
                                    .Select(
                                        dn =>
                                            new
                                            {
                                                DnoId = dn.DnoId,
                                                Dno = dn.Dno,
                                                DfullList =
                                                    x.ToList()
                                                        .Select(df => new {DfullId = df.DfullId, Dfull = df.Dfull})
                                            })
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your classes mapped correctly as thus and create your classes that map to these which can be easily serialized/de-serialized.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<DnoList> DnoLists { get; set; }
}

public class DnoList
{
    public int DnoId { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; }
    public List<DfullList> DfullLists { get; set; }
}

public class DfullList
{
    public int DfullId { get; set; }
    public string Dfull { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have similar Structure of class but how do I query and fill in appropriate way ?

Comment: What database do you have, are you using an ORM such as Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes I am using linq (DBML)

Comment: Please add code where you are currently selecting the data from your database.