# loop through list to return nested array object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have table with output

```
ClientName      Dno     DnoId     Dfull        DfullId
ClientA        AB342A   16711   AB342A-J2015    1
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J20131   2
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J20151   3
ClientB        AB544A   6648    AB544A-J2015T   4
ClientB        BD944A   6679    BD944A-D20131   5
ClientC        CA778A   12073   CA778A-J20151   6
```

and I want to return JSON Object like below

```
[{  
    "ClientName":"ClientA",
    "DnoList":[  
      {  
        "DnoId":"16711",
        "Dno":"AB342A",
        "DfullList":[  
          {  
            "DfullId":"1",
            "Dfull":"AB342A-J2015"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "ClientName":"ClientB"
    "DnoList":[  
      {  
        "DnoId":"6648",
        "Dno":"AB544A",
        "DfullList":[  
          {  
            "DfullId":"2",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J20131"
          },{  
            "DfullId":"3",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J20151"
          },{  
            "DfullId":"4",
            "Dfull":"AB544A-J2015T"
          }
        ]
      },
      {  
        "DnoId":"6679",
        "Dno":"BD944A",
        "DfullList":[ {  
            "DfullId":"5",
            "Dfull":"BD944A-D20131"
          } ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Classes I am using for this output is as below

```
public class MyData
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<DnoList> DnoLists { get; set; }
}

public class DnoList
{
    public int DnoId { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; }
    public List<DfullList> DfullLists { get; set; }
}

public class DfullList
{
    public int DfullId { get; set; }
    public string Dfull { get; set; }
}
```

and linq query and class I am using is as below

```
public class Client
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public int DnoId { get; set; }
        public string Dno { get; set; }
        public string Dfull { get; set; }
        public int DfullId { get; set; }
    }

var objlist = from tblA in context.TableA
    join tblB in context.TableB on tblA.lng_clientid equals tblB.lng_id
    where tblA.int_deleted.Equals(0)                              
    select new Client()
    {
        ClientName = tblA.str_client,
        DnoId = tblA.lng_dnoid,
        Dno = tblA.str_dno,
        Dfull = tblA.str_dfull,
        DfullId = tblA.lng_id
    };
```

But I am stuck that How can I loop through this add it three classes above to make desired output

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to loop through data to return Object in Web api c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938416/efficient-way-to-loop-through-data-to-return-object-in-web-api-c-sharp)